# Skype Modification?

Tags: macos, skype

Ok I have 2 questions.

First of all, how would I mod the desktop version of skype?  I'm mainly at a loss as to how to go about modifying, as I don't have any experience in modifying stuff (besides minecraft plugins).

I'm on a Mac (OSX Yosemite), and I know c#, javascript, java, and python.

My other question is, would this go against Skype's ToS?

Thanks, anything helps.

Answer (score 0):

All i can answer is, it would violate skype TOS indeed
You'll be editing the skype software itself called as modding.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I saw another question about this, but it was 5 years old, so I dont think it would work anymore.